# publish array 3 dim

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi,
i have 3 variables with type double and i want to publish them on array 3Dim.
do you have any idea about this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/232465/publish-array-3-dim/) by [Emilien](https://answers.ros.org/users/26246/emilien/) on ROS Answers with karma: 167 on 2016-04-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to [create a msg file](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv) with the following contents:

```
double[3] my_array
```

... or alternatively

```
double myvar1
double myvar2
double myvar3
```

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2016-04-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Emilien](https://answers.ros.org/users/26246/emilien/) on 2016-04-21**:
please can you explain it more?

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2016-04-21**:
Please go through the linked tutorial. When you have specific questions, open another question here.